# Abstract Designing Pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns

I was learning Abstract Designing Pattern and I have created the below code for understanding. My question is why I am seeing 'None' in the output of this code.
I have created a Chair and Bed of two types Modern and Old. And I have created a factory for each type for producing that type of product.

Just getting started so maybe it's some silly mistake that I can't find :))

**Code:**

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Chair(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_type():
        pass

class ModernChair(Chair):
    def get_type(self):
        print("Modern Chair!")

class OldChair(Chair):
    def get_type(self):
        print("Old Chair!")
        
class Bed(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_type():
        pass

class ModernBed(Bed):
    def get_type(self):
        print("Modern Bed!")

class OldBed(Bed):
    def get_type(self):
        print("Old Bed!")

class BaseFactory(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_chair():
        pass
    
    @abstractmethod
    def get_bed():
        pass

class ModernFactory(BaseFactory):
    @staticmethod
    def get_chair():
        return ModernChair()
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_bed():
        return ModernBed()

class OldFactory(BaseFactory):
    @staticmethod
    def get_chair():
        return OldChair()
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_bed():
        return OldBed()

m_chair = ModernFactory.get_chair()
m_bed = ModernFactory.get_bed()
o_chair = OldFactory.get_chair()
o_bed = OldFactory.get_bed()

for obj in list([m_chair, m_bed, o_chair, o_bed]):
    print(obj.get_type())
```

**Output:**

```
Modern Chair!
None
Modern Bed!
None
Old Chair!
None
Old Bed!
None
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `get_type` methods should `return` their output, not `print` it. You are printing the output of your methods, which is `None` as you didn't explicitely set a return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this code.

The first is that your `get_type` methods don't actually get anything. Instead, they print. This means you have misnamed your functions.

Second, you iterate over `list([m_chair, m_bed, o_chair, o_bed])`. While this is correct, there is no reason whatsoever not to iterate over `[m_chair, m_bed, o_chair, o_bed]` - in fact, exactly the same thing happens, but with higher performance.

When you call `print(m_chair.get_type())`, the method `get_type` in the `ModernChair` class is called. This prints `"Modern Chair!"` and then reaches the end of the function without a return statement. In Python, when a function reaches its end without a return statement, an implicit `return None` is added. This means that `m_chair.get_type()` will evalute to `None`, which is then printed.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks, Mark.